# Allow updating an attribute of a User model only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

An admin account creates a user account, this automatically generates a username determined by the user's first and surname.
Once the username is created I want the user to be able to update it only once - Note: This can be at any time or after multiple logins, but once the username has been changed once it needs to be set in stone.

Using Rails and simple_form. The edit form is below.

```
= simple_form_for(current_user) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name, required: true, label: 'Name'
    = f.input :username, required: true
    = f.input :email, required: true
    = f.input :password, required: true, placeholder: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length)
    = f.input :password_confirmation, required: true


  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, "Update Profile", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg'
```

Admin/Users controller.

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.password = SecureRandom.base64()
    nameArray = @user.name.split(' ')
    @user.username = nameArray[0][0].downcase + nameArray[-1][0..6].downcase
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        @user.send_reset_password_instructions
        format.html do
          redirect_to [:admin, @user],
          notice: "#{@user} was successfully created. A confirmation email was sent to: #{@user.email}"
        end
      else
        format.html do
          flash[:alert] = "User #{@user} already exists, or you have not filled in all of the required fields."  
          render :new
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add new column to User  like :edited

```
def change
  add_column :users, :eited, :boolean, default: false
end
```

In your model User add calback after_update

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :set_edited!
  before_update :check_if_edited!

  def is_edited?
    edited?
  end

  private

  def check_if_edited!
    # there you can set the error message or what you want
    errors.add(:base, :invalid, message: "Your message")) if edited?
  end

  def set_edited!
    transaction do
      self.edited = true
      self.save!
    end
  end
end
```

In your user controller add restriction to update user if is_edited?

```
def update
  if current_user.is_edited?
    // preform action
  end
end
```

P.S. migrate logic to assign attributes to model User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :assign_attributes

  private

  def assign_attributes
    transaction do
      self.password = SecureRandom.base64()
      name_array = name.split(' ')
      self.username = nameArray[0][0].downcase + nameArray[-1][0..6].downcase
     self.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me the best way would be to use call_back in user model:

```
before_update{|user|
  user.write_user_name_changed unless user.created_at == user.updated_at
}



 def write_user_name_changed
    self.user_name_changed = params[:username]
    true
  end
```

Comment: Unless there are other things that can update `.updated_at` on the User record.